# PGSQL syntax to fetch last year's last two month records from current year Jan or Feb

Tags: postgresql

can anyone tell me the logic of getting last year's last 2 months records from the next year Jan or feb ?. For eg: I want to compare the sales from Jan 2016 as current month and Dec 2015 as previous month and Nov 2015 as two months before. I tried like this, but not working if it is for Jan or feb

```
(case when extract(month from m.validfrom) = extract(month from current_date)-1 then 'Previous Month'
when extract(month from m.validfrom) = extract(month from current_date)-2 then 'Two Months Before'
when extract(month from m.validfrom) = extract(month from current_date) then 'Current Month' end ) as month,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

```
case date_trunc('month', m.validfrom)
    when date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 month') then 'Previous Month'
    when date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '2 month') then 'Two Months Before'
    when date_trunc('month', current_date) then 'Current Month'
end as month
```